# How configure router-view default page in index.js while using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my project, I use vue.js 2.9.

I have detail.vue page, some html code is like:

```
<div class="tab">
 <div class="tab-item">
   <router-link to='/goods' >goods</router-link>
 </div>
 <div class="tab-item">
  <router-link to='/ratings' >ratings</router-link>
 </div>
 <div class="tab-item">
   <router-link to='/seller' >seller</router-link>
 </div>
</div>
<keep-alive>
  <router-view ></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

And the index.js content is like:

```
export default new Router({
routes: [{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '/detail',
  name: 'Detail',
  component: Detail,
  children: [{
    path: '/goods',
    name: 'Goods',
    component: Goods
  },
  {
    path: '/ratings',
    name: 'Ratings',
    component: Ratings
  },
  {
    path: '/seller',
    name: 'Seller',
    component: Seller
  }]
}]
})
```

The problem is the result of router-view after opening detail.vue page is Home, but not goods.

The default router-view result of openning detail.vue page should be goods, not the home page.

I have added content in detail.vue

```
components: {
'v-header': header,
'v-goods': goods
 },
 routes: [{
 path: '/',
 name: 'goods',
 component: goods
 }]
```

and i added content in App.vue

```
<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
import Home from '@/components/home/Home'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
   }]
  }
</script>
```

But unlucky, it failed again. it showed nothing when open detail.vue. How to configure the index.js? who can help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "the default result"?

Comment: Why should the default router-view result of opening detail.vue be goods? Shouldn't it be detail.vue?

Comment: @MiguelCoder, when opening detail.vue page, router-view should be goods components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question, you should use children property in the routes as follows:

```
routes: [{
   path: '/',
   name: 'Home',
   component: Home
  }, 
  {
   path: '/detail',
   name: 'Detail',
   component: Detail,
   children: [
     {
      path: '/ratings',
      name: 'Ratings',
      component: Ratings
     }, 
     {
      path: '/seller',
      name: 'Seller',
      component: Seller
     },
     {
      path: '/goods',
      name: 'Goods',
      component: Goods
     }]
   }]
```

and also you should specify < router-view > in app.vue for the default route(Home) and in detail.vue specify < router-view > for the route specific to that particular component as shown above. No need to change the template you mentioned over here.

Comment: yes, thankyou. I have added / path in children for loading detail.vue first, and it works